# get the unique id of div generated using while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<?php

include('config/config.php');

if($_POST)
{
    $q=$_POST['searchword'];
    $sql_res=mysql_query("select uid,username,email,media,country from select_tag where username like '%$q%' or email like '%$q%' order by uid LIMIT 5");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
    {
        $username=$row['username'];
        $email=$row['email'];
        $media=$row['media'];
        $country=$row['country'];
        $b_username='<b>'.$q.'</b>';
        $b_email='<b>'.$q.'</b>';
        $final_username = str_ireplace($q, $b_username, $username);
        $final_email = str_ireplace($q, $b_email, $email);
        ?>
        <div class="display_box" id="display">
        <img align="top" src="<?php echo $media; ?>" style="width:40px; height:40px;"  />
        <span class="name" id="name" data-ruid="<?php echo addslashes($row[uid]); ?>" style="position: relative;top:11px;" onclick="showselected_people();"><?php echo $final_username; ?></span></div>

        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

so i edited the post but now i m getting error "Use of undefined constatnt uid"..???

Comment: `should be captured`, `further progress`, what are you trying to do?

Comment: as written, your html is invalid since ALL of the div.displaybox and span.name will have the **SAME** id. duplicate IDs are not permitted in DOM documents.

Comment: There is something we're forgetting here...aww yes **[BIG RED WARNING](http://us3.php.net/mysql_query)**

Comment: so how can i get the unique id of each div by generating div from while loop......

Comment: Use a counter: `$i`, `id="name-<?php echo $i; ?>"`, incremented in each loop.

Comment: duplicate IDs do indeed function in the dom. window.ID then returns a collection instead of a node. it won't validate and it's a very poor practice, but it's wrong to say that the DOM can't handle them.

Answer (score 1):

you can use uid in your span like this:

```
 <span class="name" id="name-<?php echo $row[uid] ?>" style="position: relative;top:11px;"><?php echo $final_username; ?></span></div>
```

then in jquery:

```
$(".name").on('click', function(){
    var arr = this.id.split('-');
    var id = arr[1]; //its your uid
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By this code, when you'll click on div, there will be store the user name in `userName` variable.

```
  var parElem = document.getElementById('display');
    parElem.addEventListener('click', getName);
    var userName;
    function getName(){
        var allspan = this.getElementsByTagName('span'); 
        for(var i=0; i<allspan.length; i++){
            if(allspan[i].id == 'name'){
                 userName = allspan[i].innerHtml;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, but then he needs to send it back to the server and do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

Though @Awlad Liton's solution is adequate, I usually prefer placing such data in separate attributes.

```
<span class="name" id="name" data-ruid="<?php echo addslashes($row['uid']); ?>" ....
```

Then in JS:

```
$(".name").on('click', function() {
    var rowId = $(this).attr("data-ruid");
    //and maybe even clean it up
    rowId = parseInt(rowId);
});
```

Comment: And, if using HTML5, use a `data-*` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, Sergiu. Corrected it. BTW, you have the EXACT name as one of my best friends. I was shocked for a moment for seeing him here :).

Comment: I copied it and didn't notice that you didn't place slashes around 'uid'